# Understanding the affect of sample composition changes on mean over time

Tags: regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, mean, group-differences

I am working on a problem that is similar to the following.

Suppose I am interested in understanding what is causing the mean price of apples to change from month to month.

My dataset has a similar structure to the following:

| Region | Apple Vendor | Apple Size | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Region 1 | Vendor A | Small | 01-01-2022 | 1.00 |
| Region 2 | Vendor A | Small | 01-01-2022 | 1.10 |
| Region 2 | Vendor B | Small | 01-01-2022 | 1.50 |
| Region 1 | Vendor A | Small | 02-02-2022 | 1.00 |
| Region 3 | Vendor C | Large | 02-02-2022 | 2.00 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Region 20 | Vendor 40 | Medium | 12-12-2022 | 1.87 |

where the average monthly rate for an apple is:

| Jan | Feb | Mar | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.11 | 1.21 | 1.15 | ... |

While not strictly true for my real problem, if it is simpler we can assume that the price of an apple will always be the same if the Region, Vendor, and Size are the same. Also, assume that the number of samples and group proportions vary from month to month.

I want to understand how changes in my sample's mix of Region, Vendor, and Size affect the monthly mean rate of apples. For example, I would like to be able to say something like the average rate of apples increased in February mostly due to an increase in the proportion of Vendor D in our sample.

Looking for advice on the best way to approach this problem as I am really not sure what area I should even group this problem into.